# Xamarin forms, working with a OnPropertyChanged with a INT value

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have one button on my `MasterDetailPage` changing the value on an INT (named App.value1) depending on what you click looking like this:

```
void click1 (object s, EventArgs a)
{
    if (App.value1 == 0) {

        App.value1 = App.value1 + 1;

    } else {
        App.value1 = 0;
    }
}
```

And I want this click function to immediately change the value on my StartPage (another `ContentPage`). So I have created a viewmodel looking like this, where I try to work with the current value:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged (string propertyName)
{
    var changed = PropertyChanged;
    if (changed != null) {

        PropertyChanged (this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs (propertyName));    
    }
}

public int currentValue {

        get {
            return App.value1;  
        }

        set {

            if (App.value1 == 0) {
                App.value1 = 0;

            } else {

                App.value1 = 1;
            }

        }   


    }
```

And this is the `StartPage` where I want the value of the INT to update immediately depending on what you clicked on at the `MasterDetailView`.

```
public StartPage ()
{
        var ourView = new StartPageViewModel ();

        ourCurrentValue = ourView.currentValue;
}

protected async override void OnAppearing() 
{
    LoadData();
}


private async Task<List<Pin>> LoadData() //I work with pins here (not showing that code though as it is irrelavant.
{
    if (ourCurrentValue == 0) {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine ("Value is 0");
    }

    else {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine ("Value is 1");
    }
}
```

Right now I only see "Value is 0" in my log. Nothing updates when I click on my button on the `MasterDetailPage`.

UPDATED CODE:

```
public class StartPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ICommand clickCommand;
    private int currentValue;

    public  event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged (string propertyName)
    {
        var changed = PropertyChanged;
        if (changed != null) 
        {
            PropertyChanged (this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs (propertyName));    
        }
    }


    public StartPageViewModel()
    {
        ClickCommand = new Command(() => CurrentValue = CurrentValue + 1);
    }

    public ICommand ClickCommand 
    {
        get { return clickCommand; }
        set
        {
            clickCommand = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ClickCommand");
        }
    }
    public int CurrentValue 
    {
        get { return currentValue; }
        set
        {
            currentValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentValue");
        }
    }

}
```

And StartPage:

```
public StartPage ()
    {
        App.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) => OnPropertyChanged("currentValue"); // ERROR: `An object reference is requiered to access non-static member 'Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.PropertyChanged`
    }
```

Comment: The purpose of INotifyPropertyChanged is to fire the PropertyChanged event when the value of the property changes, in the setter.  Your setter is empty.  You are also using INPC on one property (currentValue) but modifying a different property App.value1.  If you want to update when value1 changes, then update value1's setter to implement INPC.  And if you are not using databinding, then you will need to manually set a PropertyChanged handler if you want it to do anything.  Finally, why is currentValue a string property if you are parsing it's value as an int?

Comment: Ok so, make a int directly instead of a string and then turn it to a int. Move the current code in my viewmodel on my getter to my setter instead? And to answer your question I am not using databinding here just changing the value of the int and making code visible depending on the current value

Comment: Updated the code with two changes now. Moved code to the setter and made the "currentValue" on my viewmodel an int directly. What is missing now? How can I manually set the propertychanged handler?

Comment: @Yannick, as @Jason wrote, when you are updating `App.value1` in your click button handler, `StartPage` doesn't even have a way to be notified that, the value changed, because it is binded to `StartPageViewModel`

Comment: Ok. It cannot reach it via the current viewmodel then? How would I need to adjust it?

Comment: Is `StartPage` a child of the `MasterDetailPage`? Maybe, they can just share the same ViewModel then?

Comment: The Masterdetailview is the Master and the StartPage is the detail. So yes I think so

Comment: They both Initialize their "components" at the same time

Comment: Also, `OnAppearing` is called once before the `StartPage` becomes visible. So, if you are not doing something in your application that would cause `OnAppearing` method to be called again then it won't be called (for example navigate to another page and then come back)

Comment: Yes exactly, that is why I need something like a propertychangedfunction right?

Comment: Yes, when you are binding to your `currentValue` property in View, then raising `PropertyChanged` event would cause View update to the new value of property

Comment: Precisely. I know what the "structure" is but not sure how to make it work with the code. With the current code, am I far off? And can you see what would need to adjust?

Comment: I would say yes, because your click button handler updates `App.value1`, but `StartPageViewModel` doesn't know anything about that.

If you would have shared ViewModel between `MasterDetailPage` and `StartPage` then you could update value from click button handler and `StartPage` would know about that because it is binded to the same property which is being updated.

Comment: Ok, do u know what kind of code I need to add or how I would need to adjust my current one?

Comment: Another possibility you have is to create event which will be responsible for notifying subscribers that `App.value1` changed and then you have to subscribe to that notification in your `StartPageViewModel` and update your `currentValue`

Comment: Via a messagingcenter function? I have heard of that but never actually used it. I would appreciate if you showed me how it could look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can proceed with something like that:

Make following changes to your `App` class and `value1` property inside that class:

```
public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private static void OnPropertyChanged (string propertyName)
{
    var changed = PropertyChanged;
    if (changed != null) 
    {
        PropertyChanged (null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs    (propertyName));    
    }
}

private static int _value1;
public static int value1
{
    get { return _value1; }
    set 
    { 
        _value1 = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("value1");
    } 
}
```

Then add this line to your `StartPageViewModel` constructor:

```
App.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) => OnPropertyChanged("currentValue");
```

In that code you are just leveraging `PropertyChanged` for your own purposes (you can even create your own event for that).
I mean `StartPageViewModel` subscribes to `PropertyChanged` event in `App`class, so it will be notified when `value1` change. And when it actually occurs, then it is invoking his own `PropertyChanged` to notify View about `currentValue` change.

However, I would say better solution is to share View Model between `MasterDetailPage` and `StartPage`, because using global state makes your solution hard to understand :

```
public class SharedViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ICommand clickCommand;
    private int currentValue;

    /* INotifyPropertyChanged implementation */

    public SharedViewModel()
    {
        ClickCommand = new Command(() => CurrentValue = CurrentValue + 1);
    }

    public ICommand ClickCommand 
    {
        get { return clickCommand; }
        set
        {
           clickCommand = value;
           OnPropertyChanged("ClickCommand");
        }
    }
    public int CurrentValue 
    {
        get { return currentValue; }
        set
        {
           currentValue = value;
           OnPropertyChanged("CurrentValue");
        }
    }
}
```

And you need to use the same instance of `SharedViewModel` in `MasterDetailPage` as well as `StartPage`

Comment: Gives me errors when I change from a protected virtual void to a private static void in my viewmodel. I also get these two errors on  `OnPropertyChanged("value1");` and `App.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) => OnPropertyChanged("currentValue");` it says: `An object reference is requiered to access non-static member 'Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.PropertyChanged'`

Comment: Your `App` class is View Model?

Comment: I am so lost right now haha. Should I add this code in my projectname CS file? `public class App : Application` inside there?

Comment: First piece of code, you should add to file where `App` class reside, the second part is just one line to `StartPageViewModel` constructor

Comment: Yes, in that file where is your `value1` defined

Comment: I am going for the second option. Check my updated code in the post (scroll down). I get this error: `An object reference is requiered to access non-static member Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.PropertyChanged`

Comment: I get so much errors from this. When I use the first option I get this error: `Keyword "this" is not valid in a static property, static method or static field initializer`

Comment: I have not got it quite right yet. But I have a good base to start off. I will most likely make a new post within a few hours with progress. Thanks

Comment: If you go for a second option, then you don't need this whole **static** stuff in `App` class. Anyway, the error is actually quite right, I didn't noticed that there is a `this` keyword in event raise. I modified code, so it should works fine now.